# What is the cheapest way to give someone 1 mol of gold?

Tags: mole

Let's say I've lost a bet to a friend who is a molecular biologist and I have to give her 1 mol of gold. What is the cheapest way to accomplish this?

It was a fun bet so I don't need to give her the gold, but I want to do it anyway. Just in a fun way.

Are there scientific tricks I can pull on her? Here are some ideas that might help:

- Is there a different definition of a mole?
- Is there a cheap and useless chemical compound containing gold?
- Is there a kind of wordplay I can pull?

Comment: (1) No. (2) No. (3) Maybe, but that's not a question on chemistry.

Comment: Using 1E+10 m³ of seawater would not be practical, but it would give about 1 mol of gold.

Comment: [Golden mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_mole)

Comment: Send it to me immediately, and I'll forward it to your friend.

Comment: @IvanNeretin About the word play, I meant something in the language of chemistry. Since I don't know much about chemistry, I thought chemists might have some jokes and stuff between themselves.

Comment: Czech language calls "mol" a small flying insects, eating either wool (clothing moth), either stored food. (mill moth). So take a dead moth and make it golden by golden dust/glitters or whatever it is called. // Otherwise 1 mol of gold is about 197 g, so think twice.

Comment: @Poutnik What if I give her 197g of another element and call it a DIY gold pack? "Just open the pack, perform fusion and get your gold*!" *results may vary

Comment: Use Fool’s gold. Very cheap. Too bad this was not posted six days ago, on Mole Day.

Comment: The only stable gold isotope 197Au is possible to make from the stable platinum isotope  196Pt by neutron absorbtion  and following beta decay. :-) But  it would be very expensive :-D

Comment: @EdV If the she-friend realizes it is fool's gold, she would be unhappy for several reasons. :-D Hopefully in good joking mood only. :-D

Comment: @Poutnik Well it doesn't have to be practical, but physically possible.

Comment: Another option is lead iodide $\ce{PbI2}$ which was called "mad gold". Made of yellow, shiny platelets looking like gold. it is easily prepared by mixing a lead nitrate solution ($\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$) and a potassium iodide solution ($\ce{KI}$). The reaction produces a yellow precipitate of $\ce{PbI2}$ which is not crystalline. But by diluting the mixture and heating it to $100$°C, the precipitate is soluble. And by cooling it down slowly, it produces wonderful shiny platelets of "mad gold". It is wonderful ! It can be filtered. My students are always filled with wonder when doing it in the lab.

Comment: There is also a critter which is named "mole." So a gold plated statue of the critter would be a "mole of gold."

Comment: @MaxW See Loong's comment :)

Comment: If you really want to do it, go to used jewelry or coin shops. They often sell gold at a multiple of the spot price in forms that do not have additional value, for use by jewelry makers and other artists. Purity is not assured, but these sources are much cheaper than technical materials suppliers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to  [Lamb, A. E., Anderson, C. W. N. & Haverkamp, R. G. (2001). The induced accumulation of gold in the plants Brassica juncea, Berkheya coddii and chicory. Chem New Zealand. 2011, 34-36.](http://Lamb,%20A.%20E.,%20Anderson,%20C.%20W.%20N.%20&%20Haverkamp,%20R.%20G.%20(2001).%20The%20induced%20accumulation%20of%20gold%20in%20the%20plants%20Brassica%20juncea,%20Berkheya%20coddii%20and%20chicory.%20Chem%20New%20Zealand.%202011,%2034-36.), the leaves, stems, and roots of the mustard plant contain $\approx \pu{100 mg}$ of gold per kg of dried biomass in certain soils.  So if a fresh mustard plant weighs, say, $ \pu{200 g}$, and has a water content of $85\%$, then its dried weight is $\pu{30 g = 0.030 kg}$, and it would thus contain $\pu{ {100 mg gold}//kg dried biomass}\, \times \, \pu{0.030 kg dried biomass = 3.0 mg gold = 0.0030 g gold}$.

To get a mole of gold ($\pu{197 g)}$, you would need $\pu{197 g}$/$\pu{0.0030 g = 66,000}$ mustard plants.

Mustard seeds are very small: $\pu{1 to 2 mm}$ in diameter.  Let's assume they're spherical, and $\pu{1.5 mm}$ in dia.  That gives a volume equal to:
$\frac{4}{3} \pi \Big( \frac{1.5\pu{mm}}{2}\Big) ^3 =  \pu{1.8 mm^3} =\pu{ 0.0018 cm^3}$.  If we assume their specific gravity is about the same as water's, each seed would weigh about $\pu{0.0018 g}$.

To get $\pu{66,000}$ mustard plants, we'd need many more than $\pu{66,000}$ seeds, since some would not be viable.  I don't know what the viability of mustard seeds is, but let's say $\pu{100,000}$ would do it.

$\pu{100,000}$ mustard seeds would weigh $\pu{180 g}$.

So you can give your friend about $\pu{200 g}$ of mustard seeds, and tell her all she has to do is plant these in appropriate soil conditions, and she will have herself $\pu{1 mole}$ of gold.

Comment: Maybe this calculation is valid in New Zealand. But I doubt that this mustard can contain gold when growing in a soil which has no gold.

Comment: But it would make better seasoning than gold, no?

Comment: (+1) For bringing in a gold hyperaccumulator and doing the math! My favorite hyperaccumulator is the New Caledonian tree that has blue-green latex (“rubber tree-like”) sap that is more than 1 M in nickel citrate.

Comment: @Maurice:  I already already included qualifiers about soil conditions—twice— in my answer:  *"in certain soils"* *"in appropriate soil conditions"*.

Comment: The nice thing about theorists is that they can come up with ideas that are so impractical that some chemist will now wonder if this is challenging enough.

Comment: @JamesGaidis  Yes, we can be trouble-makers, but sometimes the experimentalists come up with these schemes entirely on their own:  "Fritz Haber did research on the extraction of gold from sea water in an effort to help pay Germany's reparations following World War I.  Based on the published values of 2 to 64 ppb of gold in seawater a commercially successful extraction seemed possible. After analysis of 4,000 water samples yielding an average of 0.004 ppb it became clear that extraction would not be possible and he ended the project."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold#Seawater

Comment: Thanks @EdV!   It's ironic that this happened on a closed question, particularly since I often find myself complaining that questions have been incorrectly closed :).  So now that I have access to moderator tools (no idea what that means yet), how much trouble can I cause?

Comment: @EdV  To quote Napoleon, it seems "Glory is fleeting"  :D